# How did "trouver", which originally meant "compose", shift to mean "find"?

Tags: étymologie

Kindly see the embolded phrase below. How's the notion of inventing related to finding? Can you please expound this semantic shift?

#### troubadour [18]

> A  *troubadour* is
> etymologically someone who ‘finds’ – that is,
> ‘composes’ – songs. The word comes via French
> *troubadour* from Provençal *trobador*, a
> derivative of the verb *trobar* (whose modern
> French equivalent is *trouver*). This seems
> originally to have meant ‘compose’, and **later to
> have shifted its semantic ground via ‘invent’ to
> ‘find’**. It is not known for certain where it came
> from, but one theory traces it back via a Vulgar
> Latin **tropāre* to Latin *tropus* ‘figure of speech’
> (source of English *trope* [16]). This in turn was
> borrowed from Greek *trópos* ‘turn’, a relative of
> English *trophy* and *tropic*. If this is so, its
> ancestral meaning would be ‘use figures of
> speech’.

*Word Origins* (2005 2e) by John Ayto. p 518 Left column.

Comment: https://www.littre.org/definition/trouver

Answer (score 1):

The etymology of ***trouver*** is not well established so the shift you mention is hypothetical.

The more common etymology (the one you found in the wiktionary) states it comes from the Latin *tropus*.

An interesting alternative theory by Francesco Benozzo is that ***trouver*** would come from a Celtic verb that was part of the hunting vocabulary used in Gaul.

Other hypothesis (translated from Benozzo's source) are:

1. Latin TURBARE 'to mix', with a die 'to stir' > 'to rummage' > 'to search' > 'to find' (Diez 1861, I, 427-429);
2. Latin TURBARE 'to stir [water] to direct [fish into a net]' (Schuchardt 1903);
3. Old High German TRUOPAN, TRUOBAN (cf. Gothic drôbjan, Saxon drôbhjan) 'to stir' (Braune 1894);
4. Franconian root TOP- 'to come across, to encounter' (at the origin of Castillian topar), with a metathesis similar to that found in French *tremper* vs. Italian *temperare* (Rice 1933);
5. Latin CONTROPARE 'to compare, to compose by comparing', attested in Cassiodorus and in the Visigothic laws of the 8th century.
   Visigothic laws of the 8th cent. (Kluyver 1909, Spitzer 1940/1941);
6. Arabic TARABA 'song' (from the root T--R-B 'to provoke emotions, to stir, to move'); the word would have entered as a loan in Andalusian Romance dialects, then in Catalan and Occitan during the period of the Arab occupation of Spain (Ribera y Tarragó 1928, II, 140-143; Menocal 1982)
7. Arabic D-R-B 'to strike, to touch' and , by extension, 'to play a musical instrument', entered Castilian before the twelfth century with reference to poets who accompanied themselves with instruments (Lemay 1966)

Sources:

- [*The paleolithic continuity paradigm for the origin of the Indo-European languages*](http://www.continuitas.org/intro.html)
- *["Trouver", "trovare", "trobar": l'ipotesi celtica](http://www.continuitas.org/texts/benozzo_trouver.pdf)*, 2010  (Italian)

Comment: Chrome : ERR_CONNECTION_RESET ; Firefox : Une erreur est survenue pendant une connexion à www.continuitas.org. PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR

Comment: @Personne Pas de problème de mon côté. C'était peut-être transitoire.

Comment: D'habitude Firefox plus sécurisé bloque et Chrome sans paramétrage est plus ouvert … même résultat 3/4 d'heure plus tard, ce n'est pas la première fois que le Pb existe … pas bien grave en fait pour moi.

Comment: @Personne Je l'ouvre aussi avec Firefox. Le site est en clair, en http, pas en https, c'est peut-être ce qui coince pour toi.

Comment: « Ding Dingue Donc », c'était le grain de sable qui ne gênait pas Chrome avant, et Firefox proposait de rejeter le site, mais on pouvait passer outre — Bien vu !

Answer (score 0):

Inventing and finding can be connected in meaning : inventing, creating or composing is sometimes described as finding new ideas, or finding inspiration,

Anyway, there are still other possible sources for **trouver**. For example, Littré cites a source tracing it from latin **turbare** (to disturb, to trouble) :

> Il est certain que turbare a pu fournir la forme du mot ; Diez cite
> l'anc. portug. trovar, troubler ; le napolit. struvare, qui est le
> lat. disturbare, et controvare qui est le lat. conturbare ; on peut y
> ajouter le français truver : Es tribulations chi truverent
> [troublèrent] nus mult, Liber psalm. p. 61. Diez établit ainsi la
> série des sens : **turbare, remuer, fouiller, d'où chercher, d'où
> trouver.** Il ajoute que cette étymologie rend raison de controuver,
> controvare ; la préposition latine cum ne se joint pas d'ordinaire
> avec un verbe roman ; mais, si trouver est turbare, le mot controuver
> a été produit par conturbare, avec le changement de sens.

Here are the successive meanings mentioned: "trubare, to shake, to rummage, hence to search, hence to find"

(which seems to me even more audacious than the inventing-finding connection!)

source : https://www.littre.org/definition/trouver